# Run php artisan db:seed more than one and continue for duplicate keys insert

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, migration

I create a seeder for insert default values in database.

If i run this seeder more than one time mysql return error for duplicate key,

So my question is that **what is best approach to handle this error? And How can continue to run other seeds?**

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't run `db:seed` command multiple times. A better way is to recreate all tables and seed the data with this command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Or just run `db:seed` once after running the `php artisan migrate:refresh` command.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

Comment: Thank you .If i create migration instate of seeder is wrong approach? with migrate:refresh my data will be lost.

Comment: @raminashrafimanesh you shouldn't have real data on a local machine. Even if you need it, you should seed it too. If for some reason you don't want to do that, just run `php artisan migrate` command to create a new table, for example. And then execute only one new seeder instead of running `db:seed`.

Comment: Thank you @alexeyMezenin for your solution.

Comment: Bad solution , it will rollback all your db migrations even with `--seed` flag. It was ok with my local machine but wouldnt be with production one :(

Answer (score 4):

You can still use [truncate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#deletes) method before seeding data, this will remove duplicate key errors because the table is already empty:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class EntitiesTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {

        DB::table('table')->truncate();
        //OR
        \App\Model::truncate();

        // then insert your data here

}
```

Comment: Truncation is only permitted if none of the columns of the table are part of a foreign key: ` Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint`

Answer (score 1):

Separate your seeds to more files and in `database/DatabaseSeeder.php` just call them like so:

```
$this->call(AuthorSeeder::class);
$this->call(ContentSeeder::class);
```

But sure, you cannot duplicate keys, thats the issue you have to solve.

Answer (score 1):

[eighty8/laravel-seeder](https://github.com/eighty8/laravel-seeder)

This package solves the problem, its version controlling the seeding like laravel does for migration, has some other benefits

- Allows you to seed databases in different environments with different values.
- Allows you to "version" seeds the same way that Laravel currently handles
- migrations. Running `php artisan seed` will only run seeds that haven't already been run.
- Allows you to run multiple seeds of the same model/table
- Prompts you if your database is in production